# Sending KeyStrokes to operate Microsoft powerpoint slides

Tags: c#

Hi 
I want to operate microsoft powerpoint slides by sending key strokes to operating system 
xp or windows 7 
please help me out ..

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing in C# would you not be better using the PowerPoint COM interfaces http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.aspx to control it programmatically?